# Get and save elements info from DataTable in each pagination

Tags: javascript, dom, datatable, pagination

I am currently using a sql query to retrieve information from my database when the page loads. The result of the query is a php array **$data[]** which is passed through the DataTables plugin (jquery) **$('#table').DataTable()** to paginate the results and on the other hand I call the **save_codes()** function to **temporaly backup the values of the textarea elements in the table**, so that later the user can undo changes to the value of these.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var id_query = '<?php echo $id_query; ?>';
    $.ajax({
                url: location.origin + '/program/functions.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { 
                    consultadatetable: id_query,
                },
                dataType: 'JSON',
                async: true,
                
                success: function(data){
                    var dataSrc = [];
                    $('#table').DataTable({
                        "data":  data.data,
                        "dom": '<"top"lif>rBt<"bottom"ilp><"clear">',
                        "lengthMenu": [[50,100,150,-1], [50,100,150,"All"]],
                        select: true
                    });
                    save_codes();
                }
    });
    });
```

```
    var textareas_list = [];

    function save_codes()
    {
        textareas_list = document.querySelectorAll(".code");
        textareas_list_size = textareas_list.length;
        
        for (var i = 0; i < textareas_list_size; i++) 
        {
            var id = textareas_list[i].id;
            var value = textareas_list[i].value;
            code_list.push({identificator: id, code: value});
        }
    }
```

This function does its job perfectly when the page is loaded for the first time, the problem is that when I move to another page of the table, using the DataTables pagination feature, the **save_codes()** function is not able to update the information contained in code_list since the page is not reloading and the function is not called again.

Does anyone know how I can infer in the DataTables pagination to update the information that my function stores, so that **the information it saves in code_list always corresponds to the results of each active pagination?**

Thank you very much in advance.

The information temporarily stored by the save_codes() function must always correspond to the results of the active paging of the table.

Comment: I will write an answer for you that will solve the issue, but if you can create a snippet with a reproducible problem, then my answer could be largely improved.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution to this problem is to change `save_codes` as follows:

```
    function save_codes()
    {
        let items = document.querySelectorAll(".code:not(.initialized)");
        if (items.length === 0) {
            return; //no new items
        }
        textareas_list = items;
        textareas_list_size = textareas_list.length;
        
        for (var i = 0; i < textareas_list_size; i++) 
        {
            textareas_list[i].classList.add("initialized");
            var id = textareas_list[i].id;
            var value = textareas_list[i].value;
            code_list.push({identificator: id, code: value});
        }
    }
```

And at your success callback, instead of just `save_codes();` you could do somehing like this:

```
setInterval(save_codes, 1000);
save_codes();
```

to run `save_codes` on each second.

```js
function f() {
    console.log("a");
};
function f2() {
    console.log("b");
}
setInterval(f, 1000);
setInterval(f2(), 1000);
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your time Lajos Arpad, the problem with that solution is that the function setTimeout(save_codes, 1000); For some reason it only runs once when the page loads, do you know why this could be happening?

Comment: @CNV it was just a typo on my end. It should have been `setInterval` which executes it on every second and I should have added a separate call to `save_codes` so it it instantly executed rather than waiting for a second before it's executed for the first time. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I edited the code using setInterval and the function is executed only once :(   success: function(data){
                    var dataSrc = [];
                    $('#table').DataTable({
                        "data":  data.data,
                        "dom": '<"top"lif>rBt<"bottom"ilp><"clear">',
                        "lengthMenu": [[50,100,150,-1], [50,100,150,"All"]],
                        select: true
                    });
                    setInterval(save_codes(), 1000);
                }

Comment: Is it possible that the function called from setInterval should not have the parentheses?  I mean that the call the way I use I mean setInterval(save_codes(), 1000); it is incorrect and must be setInterval(save_codes, 1000);

Comment: @CNV `setInterval` is a function to which you need to pass two parameters: 1. A function (the callback) and 2. A number (the # of milliseconds). Now, the second parameter specifies how much time must pass between executions and how much time must pass before the first execution. So we call `save_codes` separately as well. Now, to your question: `save_codes` is a function, therefore it can be passed as a callback without a problem. However, it has no `return` statement, so it returns `undefined`. So, if you pass `save_codes` to `setInterval`, then you pass `undefined` instead of the function.

Comment: @CNV in short: `save_codes` is the `function` that you want to execute intermittently, whereas `save_codes()` is the `return` value of `save_codes`, which is `undefined` in this case. You do not intend to call `undefined` on each second.

Comment: @CNV edited my answer and added a snippet to it, which has two `setInterval` calls. One is passing the `f` `function`, whereas the other passes the result of `f2`. `f` and `f2` differ only in what they log to the console. You will see that `b` is logged only once, because `f2` is called, logs `b` and then returns `undefined`, which is being executed each second. On the other hand, `a` is logged on each second, because the `f` `function` is passed as a callback instead of its return value.